# How to change file encoding in read.sas7bdat

Tags: r, character-encoding

I am trying to import sas data in R using package sas7bdat this way :

```
require(sas7bdat)
df<- read.sas7bdat(file)
```

This is working on linux and on windows, but on linux, accentuated characters are not correctly read (when I try to view my file in the viewer, I get "?" and when I try to view it in the R console, I get "\U3e6663c" instead of my accentuated character. It's obviously an encoding problem, I think my sas file is in latin1 and R on linux try to read it in utf8, but I haven't found the option in read.sas7bdat which allowed me to change encoding. Or could I change default encoding in the R session ?

Comment: Do you get the same results using `haven::read_sas()`?

Comment: Yes you could try changing R session encoding via `options("encoding")`, see this page for details: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html

Comment: @DominicComtois : thank you, I haven't noticed this package, it works perfectly ! I tried changing encoding with "Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "fr_FR.iso88591")", it solved the problem, but I had to roll back after importing otherwise I couldn't declare variables with accentuated character in the code... with haven it's far better !